# I'm not able to run c code in vs code terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio, terminal

[This is the error that I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlSc7.jpg) When I'm trying to run code in windows 11 it's showing this error in terminal...

TERMINAL

At line:1 char:1

gcc My-c

- cd "C: /MinGW/binc/Users/DELL/Desktop/C coding/" ; if ($?)

: ObjectNot Found: (C: \MinGw\binc\U. -- sktop\C coding: String) [Set-Location], ItemNlotFoundExcep

NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNĀNNNNNNNNNNNNANN

- CategoryInfo
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

tion

I have tried everything but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Download the C/C++ Extension. It is an extension provided by Microsoft that support visual studio code. It helps in IntelliSence, debugging and code browsing of the programming code in the visual studio.
Download the C/C++ compilers. There are some popular compilers are:
GCC on Linux
GCC via Mingw-w64 on Windows
Microsoft C++ compiler on windows
Clang for XCode on MacOS

still confused??
check out.... [https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-run-a-c-program-in-visual-studio-code#:~:text=After%20writing%20the%20code%2C%20right,Alt%20%2B%20N%20from%20the%20button](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-run-a-c-program-in-visual-studio-code#:%7E:text=After%20writing%20the%20code%2C%20right,Alt%20%2B%20N%20from%20the%20button).

Comment: I have already downloaded these extension still getting this error

Comment: will you please post the error?

Comment: Yes I have uploaded the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to compile the code.

and your output is like this-->

```
gcc.exe: error: okokok.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Than what you can do is

*Step 1* Click on `file` from tab

*Step 2* Than open `folder` where `your file` is saved.

*Step 3* Now your `terminal` is ready to compile.

Comment: And if you are still not satisfied than you might check the SETUP part in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irqbmMNs2Bo&t=271s)